# Difference between docker restart & docker-compose restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose.yml` to setup docker containers. And I have started the services using `docker-compose up -d`.

Now every time I deploy the application to the server I need to restart one of the services.

Previously I used to run the container without `docker-compose` using just the `docker run` command like this: `docker run --name test-mvn -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/app test/mvn-spring-boot -d`. 
And to restart the container I used to do `docker restart test-mvn`.

But now there are two options out there `docker-compose restart` and `docker restart`. I'm not sure which one I should prefer.

I want to know **what is the difference between these two options** and which one I should use in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `docker-compose` you manage a services, typically constituting multiple containers, while `docker` manages individual containers. Thus `docker-compose restart` will restart all the containers of a service and `docker restart` only the given containers.

Assuming "one of the services" in your question refers to an individual container I would suggest `docker restart`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.